# how do i make iphone sync all contacts from Google Contacts into IPhone?

Tags: iphone, contacts, google-sync

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=1b27fcd343e0544a&hl=en (rephrased):

> if you want to sync google contacts with iphone over the air using
>   google sync, you can... sync all contacts... this way you can leave
>   your already existing contacts on iphone and sync all google contacts
>   (remember that every email which contact you except spam is put into
>   all contacts... this means veeeery lot of contacts and some people
>   find this very frustrating)

Ok it basically claims that we can sync `All Contacts` (all people we have ever contacted) to our IPhone over the air.

But right now my IPhone is syncing only `My Contacts` group and is not syncing anything outside that group. How do I make it sync `All Contacts` ?

Comment: Just put them all in "My Contacts" on Google Contacts. You can do this by selecting all contacts in each individual group in Google Contacts and using the Groups menu; if you've never organized them at all before, then they're all in "Other Contacts". It's easy to make more groups for contacts on the Google side if you want to organize them on that side. I'm not posting this as an answer, though, as it is, strictly speaking, off-topic.

Comment: @jprete is putting them all in "My Contacts" absolutely the only way? My contacts are all neatly filed and although it doesn't take much time to move them to "My Contacts", it sort of messes up the *order* i had them as. All i want is to simply want to move all my contacts into my iphone regardless of which group the contact is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get the phone to sync with a different group than My Contacts, or to sync all the contacts, but as long as you aren't using My Contacts for filing *now*, then you can have every contact in two groups - "My Contacts" for syncing and your chosen group for filing and organization.

You can do this without destroying the rest of your sorting scheme by selecting all contacts in each group in Google Contacts, opening the Groups menu, clicking the checkbox next to My Contacts until it shows up as a solid check mark (not a slash), and then clicking "apply" in the same menu. By selecting the checkbox instead of the name and using Apply, you are telling the UI to add them to My Contacts without moving them; this is a standard bit of Google UI style.